# Excel Dynamic Row Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel

So this is supposed to be a Schedule 30/31 Days on $A
and Hours Worked on $B
[Excel Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQE3l.png)

Which I want to automate the change of colors by using a formula with the next characteristics:

1. If $B has Text Or Numbers It changes to gray AND the $A on the same row should also change to gray
2. If $B doesn't have anything neither $A nor $B2 should change color

I have used this but it only works if I apply the rule to each row

[Conditional Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL9M7.png)

So I'm searching for a way to make it automatic this is what I got until now:
[Testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwX5l.png)

All I need to change is the start I need somehow to make it not do `COL()*LIN()` but kind of appending $B and getting the row with LIN() = $BLIN() doesn't work ofc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea Thanks both [@Wizhi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4552529/wizhi) and [@Harun24HR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5514747/harun24hr) only 1 rule =$B1="" applied to =$A$1:$B$31 worked for me